# Disabling window blur state

Tags: google-chrome, electron, phaser-framework

How I can disable window blur state in electron ? I have 2 window window with Phaser.js and tween animation. When window 1 is focus, animation works on window 1 and when I click on window 2 animation is stopped on window 1 and started at window 2.
How I can focus 2 window at the same time ?

Comment: There's a blur option in the BrowserWindow instantiation.

Comment: You can set the disableVisiblityChange on stage's property like this : `game.stage.disableVisibilityChange  = true;`